# no se cumple condicion del while al ingresar una opción especifica del switch JAVA

Tags: java, while

estoy haciendo un modelo de parcial para un examen de java que se viene pronto, pero al realizarlo me encuentro con este error muy molesto que no se como solucionar. Al elegir la ultima opción del switch, el programa directamente luego de hacer los parámetros indicados en el switch, vuelve a hacerme la pregunta inicial (en la cual luego de ingresar el dato se entra al switch para poder proseguir), y está bien, PERO, en el momento de hacerme esa pregunta, la condición de corte del programa ya no se cumple, y entra en un bucle del cual no se puede salir.

**ENUNCIADO:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO:**

```
    do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del pote: ");
            pote = input.nextLine();

            while(!pote.equalsIgnoreCase("z")) {

                switch (pote) {
//----------------------------------------------------------------CASO CHICO----------------------------------------------------------------
                case "c":
                    System.out.println("de cuantos gustos lo queres? 1,2,3,4");
                    cantGustos = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    while (cantGustos < 0 || cantGustos > 4) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: la cant de gustos debe ser entre 1 y 4");
                        cantGustos = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i <= cantGustos; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del gusto n°" + i);
                        nombreGusto = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Cant de calorias para " + nombreGusto + "?");
                        cantCalorias = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

                        if (cantCalorias < cantMenorCalorias) {
                            cantMenorCalorias = cantCalorias;
                            nombreGustoMenosCal = nombreGusto;
                            posMin = i;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("El gusto con menos calorias es el " + nombreGustoMenosCal + " pos: " + posMin);
                    contChico++;
                    contTotal++;
                    break;
//----------------------------------------------------------------CASO MEDIANO----------------------------------------------------------------
                case "m":
                    System.out.println("de cuantos gustos lo queres? 1,2,3,4");
                    cantGustos = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    while (cantGustos < 0 || cantGustos > 4) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: la cant de gustos debe ser entre 1 y 4");
                        cantGustos = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    }
                    for (int j = 1; j <= cantGustos; j++) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del gusto n°" + j);
                        nombreGusto = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Cant de calorias para " + nombreGusto + "?");
                        cantCalorias = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

                        if (cantCalorias < cantMenorCalorias) {
                            cantMenorCalorias = cantCalorias;
                            nombreGustoMenosCal = nombreGusto;
                            posMin = j;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("El gusto con menos calorias es el " + nombreGustoMenosCal + " pos: " + posMin);
                    contMediano++;
                    contTotal++;
                    break;
//----------------------------------------------------------------CASO GRANDE----------------------------------------------------------------
                case "g":
                    System.out.println("de cuantos gustos lo queres? 1,2,3,4");
                    cantGustos = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    while (cantGustos < 0 || cantGustos > 4) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: la cant de gustos debe ser entre 1 y 4");
                        cantGustos = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    }
                    for (int k = 1; k <= cantGustos; k++) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del gusto n°" + k);
                        nombreGusto = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Cant de calorias para " + nombreGusto + "?");
                        cantCalorias = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

                        if (cantCalorias < cantMenorCalorias) {
                            cantMenorCalorias = cantCalorias;
                            nombreGustoMenosCal = nombreGusto;
                            posMin = k;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("El gusto con menos calorias es el " + nombreGustoMenosCal + " pos: " + posMin);
                    contGrande++;
                    contTotal++;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }

        } while (!pote.equalsIgnoreCase("z") || contGrande == MAXIMOGRANDES);
        input.close();
        System.out.println(contTotal);
        System.out.println("Cantidad de pedidos por tamaño: \n");
        System.out.println("Chico: " + contChico + "\n" + "Mediano: " + contMediano + "\n" + "Grande: " + contGrande);
    }
}
```

Comment: revisa la condición contGrande==MAXIMOGRANDES;  siempre se cumple,talvez lo tienes inicializado como 1 y contGrande++; te devuelve 1

Comment: era eso! muchas gracias